# Process builder - The formula expression is invalid: Field Task is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions

Tags: text, formula, processbuilder, picklist

This is the formula I am building to populate the Opportunity Name field in Process Builder

Here `Product_Type__c` is a Picklist field

```
[Task].Account.Name  +  '-' + TEXT([Task].Product_Type__c )
```

**Error:**

```
The formula expression is invalid: Field Task is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the correct Syntax. Not sure why i got that error. I do see the string coorectly concatenated.

```
[Task].Account.Name  +  '-' + TEXT([Task].Product_Type__c )
```